# Thermostat has no power at all but it doesn’t have batteries is wired

Tags: hvac

My thermostat just stopped working is it possible that the external breaker was kicked or shut off?would that cause the thermostat to not work because my thermostat is straight wired no batteries

Comment: Hi Steve,  you are there.  Was the breaker shut off?

Comment: Sure it's possible that the breaker tripped. Have you checked it? What kind of HVAC system is the 'stat controlling? Have you checked _that_? What, exactly, do you mean by "thermostat just stopped working"? What symptoms are you experiencing? Please [edit] your question to provide more info to help us help you.

Comment: You might want to check if the wires at the thermostat have voltage.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a fuse on the furnace or boiler or heatpump.

There is also a breaker for the furnace or boiler or heatpump, which is generally the same circuit the transformer for the thermostat power is on.

Or, the thermostat wire fom the furnace or boiler or heatpump to the thermostat could be broken.